# How do you change age settings on ROBLOX?

Tags: roblox

How do you set your age settings on ROBLOX if you accidentally set to under 13? I accidentally put *2008* instead of *1998* in the sign up section. Is there any way to change this, as in settings, age settings are greyed out.

Answer (score 6):

If your account is 13+, you can change your age at any time.

However, if your account is under 13, you can't change your age.

If you want to enjoy the features of the game without restrictions, it is best you create a new account.

According to the official Roblox website for parents,

> Roblox is a member in the kidSAFE Seal Program, which has been approved by the Federal Trade Commission as an authorized safe harbor under the Children’s Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA). We are committed to complying with COPPA to ensure the privacy of our users under the age of 13 and implementing reasonable measures to prevent them from sharing personal information via chat messages or in-game.

This means that they must "implement" "reasonable measures" such as preventing those under the age of 13 to change their age so they can access content that's not "appropriate" for their age.

The 'Children's Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA)' That Roblox must comply with can be found here:

https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/2012-31341.pdf

Comment: I’ve just encountered this problem on my son’s account. European GDPR regulations impose a legal responsibility on companies trading in the EU to ensure that personal information is accurate and up to date. If I email them saying they have his DOB wrong they have a legal obligation to amend it.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue also, and I wasn't able to find a way to set it back to my original year.

I E-Mailed Roblox about this issue and I hoped to find a way to fix this, and they said due to some sort of law, you are not able to change your age and they also can't change your age.

Sorry if this couldn't help, if nothing works, you can create another account.

Answer (score 1):

From Youtube, there is 3+ videos that represent going to [Roblox Support](https://support.roblox.com) and selecting the option that can change your age.

---

#### Communication

Once you got to the page, you have to tell them *exactly* what you asked in your question, but restated, like you accidentally changed your age to  *2008* instead of *1998*.

**Note:** It may take a few for Roblox to respond, because this explanation is common to global players. So, if possible, give a detailed explanation of why they need to change your age date back to 1998 specifically and the disadvantages of choosing 2008. Add alternative info if needed. This all will prove that your not playing around with your request.

---

#### Changes

When your age gets changed, there will be changes to gameplay:

- **Safechat.**
  There is this system called safechat that censors sensitive chat misleads and sends that don't have grammar, and  something inappropriate. This is all disabled except for inappropriate language.
- **Validation Disablement** 
  Parent's Email won't be required, and you don't need authorization to buy Robux.
- **Age Icon Switch** 
  Instead of your icon to be like *<13*, it will be *13+*. This proves that your age is changed.

---

Comment: Safechat hasn't been a thing for years. Nowadays there's a chat filter that applies to everyone, regardless of age, although it's *slightly* more insane[ahem, sorry] strict for the under-13 crowd.

Answer (score 0):

Roblox does not allow changing of your age while under 13.

However, it is *possible* that contacting support can change your age.

Roblox support, when contacted with simple note, will not change your age and point to the laws that they have to follow.

However, if you over 13, and you set your birthdate to an under 13 age, it is possible that when contacted with proof of age, the team will be confident that you are not faking it.

Therefore, if you are over 13, you may want to consider fishing up your birth certificate or driver's licence to send to the support team. With such proof of age, I don't see any reason why they can think you're faking it.

If they then play the "prove that this ID belongs to you" card,  send a video of you holding your ID and waving at the camera.

This of course, all depends on whether you are comfortable sharing a photo ID, and your own face with a support team in San Mateo. It's also a long shot, but it's got enough merit to consider.

Comment: It should be noted that large companies often respond with copy-paste messages, so this is like you said a long shot.

Comment: @Penguin Do you think you still might be refused an age change even with proof of age, and a video of you waving at the camera holding your ID?

Comment: yes i really do because they dont care enough

Answer (score -1):

I would just make another account. To protect under-13 players, roblox has age restrictions. Now, if kids could change the age listed on their account, they could play all sorts of corrupting games. So, they aren't allowed to change it after it's set. Unfair? Probably, but such are the laws. However, parents probably would not let kids play roblox if it didn't have those restrictions. So perhaps they are okay.

Answer (score -1):

As stated above, there is no way to change your age if your age is under 13. If you email Roblox, they will say that they are unable to change the age due to their commitment to COPPA law (Children's Online Privacy Protection Act). The best thing would be to create a new account or wait until Robox believes that you have "passed" the age of 13. For more information you can check out Roblox's Parent's Guide:

https://corp.roblox.com/parents/

Answer (score -2):

To change your age on Roblox you must:

1. Open the Roblox home page.
2. Go to the top right corner and click on "settings".
3. A page called "My Settings" should open up.
4. Scroll down until you see "Birthday". If your account age is under 13, you will not be able to change your age.
5. Enter in a new birthday.
6. Click "Save".

Know that you have changed your birthday / age.