# How come roblox has the ''Change Age'' Choice on their roblox support program if they wont even let you change your age?

Tags: roblox

I was born in 2007, when I was a kid and created my roblox account I just typed in a random birthday (I typed in 2015.) Ever since then, I had to deal with hashtags and all kinds of other stuff. I dont wanna create another account because if I did. I would lose all my progress in my groups, My games and all my robux, aswell as friends. So I emailed roblox and chose the ''Change age'' choice. When they emailed me back they said they cant due to COPPA laws. So Im confused on why they would even add that choice if they wont even let you change your age.
I know this is long but i really need a answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change age settings on ROBLOX?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341248/how-do-you-change-age-settings-on-roblox)

Answer (score 2):

[This page should give some explanation](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031323611-How-Do-I-Change-My-Age-):

> Age Under 13

> The age setting can not be changed.

> Roblox is committed to providing safety and privacy protection for our users. For this reason and because of COPPA regulations, users under the age of 13 can not change their age setting. If the birth date on the account is correct, the privacy settings will update automatically to 13+ on the user's 13th birthday. Updating age to under 13 will enable Privacy Mode. You will not be able to change the age back to 13+.

Basically: the change age feature works just fine if you put your current age in as thirteen or older, but does not function for users under thirteen; if you start out with an age of under thirteen or change your age to under thirteen, you lose access to the change age function immediately. Since you have your age on the site listed as five, your only choices are to make another account or wait eight years for the account to age up naturally.

The "why" of this is complicated and outside the scope of Arqade, but for the simplest version of an explanation: COPPA laws mean Roblox could be fined massive $$$$$$ if they're caught advertising to kids under thirteen years old, so in order to save themselves from possible fines they have to keep you in Privacy Mode no matter what if you ever tell them you're under thirteen.

Comment: Can you contact support with proof of age to set your age above 13? Say I have a photo ID with my birthdate.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 You can always try to contact them with a picture of your ID to provide substantial evidence you're older than 13. Just claiming you are will likely not work.

Comment: I told that I can have my parents confirm I am 13, But providing a ID will most likely work, Thanks for the help.